# MySQL UNIQUE key not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building as type on inventory table that keeps track of stock by 6 different factors. I am using an I query much like this one:

```
INSERT INTO inventory ( productid, factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4, factor5, factor6, quantity, serial_number)
VALUES (242332,1,1,1,'V67',3.30,'NEW',10,NULL)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `quantity` = VALUES(`quantity`) + quantity;
```

The `inventory` table has a UNIQUE KEY for ( productid, factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4, factor5, factor6, serial_number ). For some reason, it is not picking up on the key and just `INSERT`ing instead of `UPDATE`ing. Can anyone offer an explanation why? What am I missing?

Here is the table create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `inventory` (
    `stockid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `productid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `factor1` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `factor2` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `factor3` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `factor4` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    `factor5` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    `factor6` enum('A','B','C','D','NEW') NOT NULL,
    `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `serial_number` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`stockid`),
    UNIQUE KEY `serial_number` (`serial_number`),
    UNIQUE KEY `productid_2` (`productid`,`factor1`,`factor2`,`factor3`,`factor4`,`factor5`,`factor6`,`serial_number`),
    KEY `productid` (`productid`),
    KEY `factor1` (`factor1`),
    KEY `factor2` (`factor2`),
    KEY `factor3` (`factor3`),
    CONSTRAINT `books_stock_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`productid`) REFERENCES `produx_products` (`productid`),
    CONSTRAINT `books_stock_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`factor1`) REFERENCES `table_factor1` (`factorid`),
    CONSTRAINT `books_stock_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`factor2`) REFERENCES `table_factor2` (`factorid`),
    CONSTRAINT `books_stock_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`factor3`) REFERENCES `table_factor3` (`factorid`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

More in-depth:

The purpose of this table is to hold stock quantities. I think this is pretty straight forward. The factors that separate these quantities are as follows:

- factor1 = storeid (the unique indentifier for the store that ownes this quantity).
- factor2 = supplierid (the unique indentfier for the supplier that we got the quantity from)
- factor3 = warehouseid (unique identifier for the warehouse where it resides)
- factor4 = locationid (unique string for the location. Its physically painted on the shelf)
- factor5 = cost (what we paid for each of the quantity)
- factor6 = condition (enum ['NEW','USED','RENTAL','PREORDER']. The first three are easy, the fourth is for quantites we ordered, want to sell, but have not received it yet.)

I know this is a hefty key but I am forced to keep it this way. I have had many suggestion to move cost or condition to the product table. I cannot do this. The cost isn't always the same since we buy a lot from auctions or other places with very variable costs and conditions.

I hope this helps more to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: Just as a general comment, that's quite a key you've got there. Generally a synthetic key might be recommended (and wouldn't serial number be unique - if not, it's not a great serial number). Your create table statement would be helpful. `show create table inventory`

Comment: I will post the create statement in a minute. There is a second unique key explicitly for `serial_number`. `serial_number` must be part of this key too since this table holds serialize and unserialized stock. Otherwise, I can only have one unserialized stock for each set of factors.

Comment: 1. See normalization (at least in respect of factors 1 through 3)

Comment: How is my data not normalized?

Comment: Create a fiddle.So in your existing data,`for your unique keys`,there is a duplicate in your to be inserted values?

Comment: factors 1 thru 3 are nessessary. I stipped a lot of my variable names for simplicity sake. factor1 is the storeid that owns it, factor2 is the warehouseid that it is in, and the factor3 is the supplierid that we bought it from. These are normalized.

Comment: fiddle? Unless I am not thinking of the same thing here (jsFiddle) is for javascript, not sql.

Comment: @Wesley: could you describe in your question what the factors are, and why you wish to make such a large composite key? If people understand _why_ you are doing this they may be able to advise further.

Comment: @halfer. Thanks. Its wasn't retailation, it was a request for more info.

Comment: Ah, you've added some of your factors as a comment. Sounds like you could have an auto-increment primary key, and just make those foreign keys? Although: I wonder if a product of a particular type will always be bought from a single supplier? If you can get a product from more than one supplier, one could argue that is a different product? If so, that will help you normalise further.

Comment: @Wesley, thanks. I modified my comment after your edit `:)`.

Comment: Yes, technically products with the same catid, from different suppliers are technically the same. But I have been asked to keep track of them by supplier since we cannot control the product quality. So in order to report which supplier the quantity came from, I must keep it seperate.

Comment: Also, I'd say `locationid` should just be unique on its own - unless you can have more than one thing in the same location? `cost` being part of the uniqueness key seems strange as well - that implies dups are okay as long as they cost a different amount, but if the rest of those keys are otherwise identical, that must refer to the exact same thing?

Comment: yes, most of our locations are 4 foot by 4 foot by 4 foot pallet racking. So a pallet in that space could hold quite a few products, not nessessarily the same products though. We will store things where ever the fit really. And like I explained in my edit, cost has to stay with the stock entry because we buy at auctions and such, our cost could really be all over the place.

Comment: Last contribution: I _still_ don't see any explanation as to why it is part of the unique key. As I say, as it stands, the uniqueness key seems like it could lose at least two elements. (Btw, if you wish to ping a particular person, use their @name. I don't have to here, since it is on your question).

Comment: @halfer, which two? inventory counts have these six factors because thats how we search for our inventory. There are times have to have seperate counts for each and know which items came from auctions and how much we paid for each. Our warehouse managers need to query against locations see exactly where it is on our property. the condition is pretty obvious. And if I drop the supplierid, then I have no way of reporting how much inventory we own from 1 supplier and where that inventory is. I don't see how I could drop any of that information.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mysql allows multiple NULLs in an unique constraint.In your `serial_number` column replace `NULL` with a value and the constraint is triggered,see:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dbd19/1

> a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can
>   contain NULL

[Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Make the column NOT NULL and use `''` which is empty.

Comment: WHOA!! sqlfiddle.com!! I like I like. Thanks for the new toy!

Comment: Ok. this explains my problem a little more. how can I fix it though. Not all stock has a serial_number. only serialized inventory does. serialized inventory will always have a count of 1. I use a stored porcedure to ensure this.

Comment: I had to drop the UNIQUE KEY ('serial_number') because your solution makes it redundant. My only concern now is why does the INSERT statement return 2 rows changed instead of one? Is is because of the duplicate key call or is it actually changing 2 rows?

Comment: From the manual: With `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, the affected-rows value per row is `1` if the row is inserted as a new row, and `2` if an existing row is updated.

Comment: Yay! Thats what I was hoping SQL was doing. thank you.