# Solution for softdeletes in combination with unique constraints?

Tags: mysql, laravel, soft-delete

I have a table Orders, with columns `external_id`, `shop_id` and `deleted_at`. To ensure the combination of `external_id` and `shop_id` is unique, I have a unique constraint on these 3 columns.

This is because we don't count softdeleted values for the uniqueness hence if `deleted_at` equals `NULL` in Laravel it's not softdeleted but in any other case it is, which makes multiple softdeleted records possible. Example:

```
external_id        |shop_id   |deleted_at         |
-------------------|----------|-------------------|
1                  |         5|             [NULL]| <-- should be unique
1                  |         5|2019-12-19 13:45:22|
1                  |         5|2019-12-19 13:35:45|
```

This sounds great except for 1 caveat: MySQL does not enforce uniqueness on NULL values, which is important for this to work. Normally [the workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156301/mysql-unique-key-not-working) is to change the nullable default value to an empty string. However deleted_at is a timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> create table orders (external_id int, shop_id int, deleted_at timestamp);
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE orders 
> ADD COLUMN `n_deleted_at` timestamp AS (COALESCE(deleted_at, '1980-01-01')) VIRTUAL;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON orders (external_id, shop_id, n_deleted_at);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO orders (external_id, shop_id, deleted_at) VALUES (1, 5, NULL);
> INSERT INTO orders (external_id, shop_id, deleted_at) VALUES (1, 5, '2019-12-19 13:45:2');
> INSERT INTO orders (external_id, shop_id, deleted_at) VALUES (1, 5, '2019-12-19 13:35:45');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO orders (external_id, shop_id, deleted_at) VALUES (1, 5, '2019-12-19 13:35:45');
> ```
>
> ```
> Duplicate entry '1-5-2019-12-19 13:35:45' for key 'orders.idx'
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO orders (external_id, shop_id, deleted_at) VALUES (1, 5, NULL);
> ```
>
> ```
> Duplicate entry '1-5-1980-01-01 00:00:00' for key 'orders.idx'
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec3c95ab36d28ed0291c1d16069c345e)*